# Build maven project as a part of SBT build

Tags: scala, maven, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a sbt project that depends on a maven project. 
Is it possible to make that maven project into a sub-module of sbt project, and build that maven project together as a part of SBT build?

Comment: In the end, I've converted the maven projects to SBT projects.

Answer (score 7):

Try to add to your maven project build.sbt:

```
name := "mavenDep"

scalaVersion in Global := "2.10.2"

externalPom()
```

See [Sbt documentation: Maven pom (dependencies only)](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#maven-pom-dependencies-only) externalPom does not add maven repositories - just dependencies.

So you have to add manually other repositories:

```
resolvers in Global ++= Seq(
  "snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
)
```

Comment: it is not possible to use maven settings.xml file?

Answer (score 3):

You could also try this:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pom-reader

For limited sets of maven projects (i.e. ones that don't use plugins) it can pull in information from maven into sbt in a slightly better way.  However, mapping maven plugins into sbt is practically a failed task.